# Problem with writing a file to excel with spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel

I am trying to write excel file by using ruby 1.9  spreadsheet version 0.6.4.1 on windows.
Everything is going ok, 
until I get to the book.write statement 
when I write `book.write "c:/spreadsheet/excel-file.xls` 
I keep getting the following error
**No such file or directory - c:/spreadsheet/excel-file.xls**
when i am runing it from the ruby console i get the error
errono::EINVAL invalid argument. when i check in the path i see that a file was created but althought i write to it its empty

Can anyone tell me what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: the error looks self-explanatory...

Comment: @Mitch: when you're writing to a file, there shouldn't need to be a file existing there. Unless the directory is non-existent, I don't see it as self-explanatory.

Comment: Does this problem occur for you even if you're not using rails and mongrel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use windows!

According to http://pullmonkey.com/2008/02/19/errno-einval-invalid-argument/

STDOUT is nonexistent if you run mongrel as a service under windows, and errono::EINVAL is the result.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'logger'
require 'spreadsheet'
require 'stringio'

workbook = Spreadsheet::Workbook.new
worksheet = workbook.create_worksheet
worksheet[0, 0] = "Hello, World!"

ostream = StringIO.new    

workbook.write (ostream)

ostream.rewind

File.open("aFile.xls","wb") do |f|
  f.write(ostream.read)
end

puts "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

We decided that using libraries for excel is brittle. We use CSV with extension ".xls". Why? Because Excel doesn't show that nasty import box. It just opens it like a regular file. Users won't notice the difference.